# URL repeats / redirects to www after moving site to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We have a very strange problem, that seems to be related to the .htaccess. We are stuck.

We have a website, were the client wants the same 'website', with different content on a subdomain.

We copied the existing site to the subdomain.
And had to edit the .htaccess because of the rewrites in it.

Now we are getting different results on different browsers.
Safari seems to work fine.
Chrome redirects to www.subdomain.domain.nl in normal mode.
Chrome - incognito mode works fine.
Firefox - works on all pages except for the base url.
When going to subdomain.domain.nl on Firefox the url keeps repeating.
it will redirect to http://subdomain.domain.nl/subdomain.domain.nl/subdomain.domain.nl/subdomain.domain.nl/subdomain.domain.nl/subdomain.domain.nl/subdomain.domain.nl/subdomain.domain.nl/...  this continues for a bit.

Here is the .htaccess, which is a copy of the original with the rewrites for always www. version removed.

.htaccess:
    php_value upload_max_filesize 8M

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|off [NC]
RewriteCond http%1://%{HTTP_HOST} ^(https?://)(www\.)(.+\.)(.+\.)(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%3%4%5%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^image.php($|/) - [L]
# RewriteRule ^footer.php($|/) - [L]
# RewriteRule ^(vraag_verwerk.php) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(captcha.php) - [L]

 # stuff to let through (ignore)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/2014/" [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/images/" [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/css/" [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/js/" [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/admin/"
  RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]
  #

# RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?nav=$1&sub=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^favicon\.ico$ /favicon.ico [L]
RewriteRule . index.php
```

I played around with this part, removing the original, added several other possible rewrite rules I found:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|off [NC]
 RewriteCond http%1://%{HTTP_HOST} ^(https?://)(www\.)(.+\.)(.+\.)(.+)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ %1%3%4%5%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Which was originally:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

Redirect 301 /home http://www.domain.nl
```

But as I understand it, this is just to redirect the /home to the base url and add www. if not added by visitor. And removing it all together is not helping.

I'm at a loss as to what this might be. Especially since 3 browsers give different results.

Any suggestions, or are we looking in the completely wrong direction?

Kind regards,

Martijn

Comment: Different browsers behaving differently is most likely due to browser caching issues.

Comment: I would think so too, or css related for visual differences. But the URLs are behaving differently are new to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing things one line at the time & in groups I finally found that,
removing the following made it work and stopped the repeating url, which was happening on more systems.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|off [NC]
RewriteCond http%1://%{HTTP_HOST} ^(https?://)(www\.)(.+\.)(.+\.)(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%3%4%5%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I still get a redirect to www.subdomain.domain.nl on Chrome, even after clearing cache. But this seems to be only on my system and only when I go to the homepage. We tested this on multiple systems and only my chrome is doing this.
So I guess this is something with caching and has nothing to do with this .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

I'm having difficulty following what you *want* to happen.

It looks like much of the first block (everything from "RewriteRule ^image.php" to the end) can be replaced with:

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

Beyond that, it looks like you're trying to 1) turn on HTTPS globally, 2) add 'www' to hostnames, and 3) map /home to a different host? Is that correct?

If so, you should consider using the techniques outlines at https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/CanonicalHostNames - that is, rather than mucking about in .htaccess files, put a Redirect in a VirtualHost block that defines the non-preferred hostname:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  Redirect / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

The has the advantage of easier maintenance, and better request-time efficiency. (Don't have to compare a rewrite rule every request, just the initial one.)

If I am misunderstanding, please provide more detail, and I'll try again.

Comment: The first bit you mention with the fallbackresource is the bit that is working (was already there on the excisting site). And I don't feel like changing something that already works, if I do not fully understand.

The other thing that the previous version was trying to do is add www. to the hostname and '/home' was used before instead of just '/' to get to the homepage. The redirect was in place for that. But this was on the old site.

Now we want to use the same website on a subdomain.  For that I believed removing the 'www' redirects would be enough. but that gave the strange results.